# How to calculate the average number of random numbers generated?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have written a FOR loop to call a function 100 times to get 100 random numbers, I now need to calculate the average number of all the random numbers generated. How can I do this? This is where I got up to so far

```
import random

num1 = int(input("Input First number "))
num2 = int(input("Input Second number "))

for i in range(10):
  print(random.uniform(num1, num2), end = "\t")
```

Comment: Have you considered saving the numbers in some way instead of just printing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your function is only being run 10 times. You need to store the values you're generating, rather than printing them to the screen. You can do this by storing it in a list.

To get a list of 100 random variables, you could do `[random.uniform(num1, num2) for i in range(100)]`.

Then, you need to find the average of this. To get a total sum, you can do `sum(list)`. To get the number of values, do `len(list)`. If we combine this all together, we get:

```
import random

num1 = int(input("Input First number: "))
num2 = int(input("Input Second number: "))

random_numbers = [random.uniform(num1, num2) for i in range(100)]
print(sum(random_numbers)/len(random_numbers))
```

Output is:

```
>>> import random
>>> num1 = int(input("Input First number: "))
Input First number: 10
>>> num2 = int(input("Input Second number: "))
Input Second number: 20
>>> random_numbers = [random.uniform(num1, num2) for i in range(10)]
>>> random_numbers
[13.083389212287019, 12.551686149990369, 13.881302022239865, 12.5156539109837, 12.340949073439575, 13.693758114264867, 13.972147752101735, 14.111313446849902, 11.693700678679372, 18.136716333128035]
>>> print(sum(random_numbers)/len(random_numbers))
13.5980616694
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, please choose as accepted answer if it helped!

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
rand_nums = [random.uniform(num1, num2) for i in range(10)]
average = sum(rand_nums) / len(rand_nums)
```

Or if you prefer to use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
rand_nums = np.random.uniform(num1,num2,10)
average = rand_nums.mean()
```

Comment: there is [`statistics.mean()` in Python 3.4+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to store the numbers somewhere, not print them. If you use a list, you can calculate the sum and then divide by the length.

```
import random

num1 = int(input("Input First number "))
num2 = int(input("Input Second number "))

numbers = []
for i in range(10):
  numbers.append(random.uniform(num1, num2))

print(numbers)
print(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic stuff, hope this helps:

```
import random
num1 = int(input("Input First number "))
num2 = int(input("Input Second number "))

sum = 0
numbers = 100
for i in range(numbers):
  random_number = random.uniform(num1, num2)
  sum += random_number
avarage = sum/numbers
print(avarage)
```